# Не работает each в jquery

Tags: jquery

Нужно через перебор заходить на каждую страницу и нажимать кнопку.
И дождать когда кнопка будет нажата.
Но each берёт всегда только первое значение 489

```
   var arr = [
        '489',
        '1132',
        '490'
        ];
    $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
        location.href = 'https://тут адрес' + value + '/actors?deleteTill=2019-12-08T22%3A11%3A30';
      bz = $('input#confirm_deletion').prop('checked', true);
      bz1 = $('input.ignore_in_selects').val('true');
      $(".ui.button.orange").click();
      $('.ui.button.orange').submit();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос через многопоточное открытие окон в браузере chrome + автозапуск скрипта при открытие нового окна через injector, в том же хроме.

Answer (score 2):

В Вашем коде нарушены причинно-следственные связи. Код находится в странице, которая знает про числа в массиве. Вы пытаетесь перейти на другие страницы по очереди. Очевидно, что перейти Вам удастся на какую-нибудь одну из них, как мы видим - на первую.

Далее.

Код, который идет после `location.href = ...;` манипулирует элементами со страницы, на которую Вы пытаетесь перейти. Не говоря уже о том, что переход на другую страницу - операция асинхронная, этот код должен быть в той страницы, на которой есть элементы, а не на той, с которой Вы туда пытаетесь попасть.

Думаю, Вам следует, не торопясь, словами, русским языком, объяснить, что Вы хотите сделать.

---

Если я Вас правильно понял, то что Вы хотите сделать, Вам не удастся сделать из браузера. Это обычно делают (серверным) кодом, работающим с компонентой-браузером.

Comment: Как вариант еще можно хранить массив в локальном хранилище и удалять по одному при каждом переходе..

Comment: @Get-Web Только если в эти страницы можно вставить код поддерживающий выполнение такой "цепочки" вызовов. В чем я сомневаюсь.

Comment: в принципе даже если без доступа к сайта, можно использовать к примеру Greasemonkey